# Clojure sum maps with strings and numbers

Tags: clojure

Hi l have 2 maps like these (with the possibility of having multiple maps)

```
(def map1 {:a {:b 1} :c ["dog"]})
(def map2 {:a {:b 2} :c ["cat"]})
```

l need to have this as a return {:a {:b 3} :c ["dog" "cat"]}

How can l do this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution using generic functions

You could use generic functions - let's call it here `o+` (operator +) - by making use of Clojure's multiple dispatch ability. By multiple dispatch you avoid `if - else` or `cond` clauses - for distinguishing the argument types/classes - thereby the code stays extensible (further cases can be added without having to change existing code). The function at the end of the `defmulti` definition is the dispatch function. In the `defmethod` form - right before the actual function arguments list (vector), you list the dispatch case for which then Clojure looks when deciding which method to use.

```
(defmulti o+ (fn [& args] (mapv class args)))
(defmethod o+ [Number Number] [x y] (+ x y)) ;; Numbers get added
(defmethod o+ [clojure.lang.PersistentVector clojure.lang.PersistentVector]
  [x y] (into (empty x) (concat x y))) ;; Vectors concatentated
(defmethod o+ [clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap] 
  [x y] (merge-with o+ x y)) ;; Maps merged-with #'o+ (recursive definition!)
```

#### Test

You can fuse then two maps with the (now recursively defined) `o+` operator:

```
(def map1 {:a {:b 1} :c ["dog"]})
(def map2 {:a {:b 2} :c ["cat"]})

(o+ map1 map2) ;; or originally: (merge-with o+ map1 map2)
;; => {:a {:b 3}, :c ["dog" "cat"]}
```

#### Even deeper nested maps are covered

Due to the recursive character of this definition - this works also with more deeply nested maps as long as they have the same structure - and use only the defined class cases (otherwise one could add further cases):

```
(def mapA {:a {:b 2 :c {:d 1 :e ["a"] :f 3}} :g ["b"]})
(def mapB {:a {:b 3 :c {:d 4 :e ["b" "e"] :f 5}} :g ["c"]})

(o+ mapA mapB)
;;=> {:a {:b 5, :c {:d 5, :e ["a" "b" "e"], :f 8}}, :g ["b" "c"]}
```

#### Use `reduce` to add more maps at once

And as long as you can apply `o+` on two objects, you can process an arbitrary number of maps using `reduce`:

```
(def mapA {:a {:b 2 :c {:d 1 :e ["a"] :f 3}} :g ["b"]})
(def mapB {:a {:b 3 :c {:d 4 :e ["b" "e"] :f 5}} :g ["c"]})
(def mapC {:a {:b 1 :c {:d 3 :e ["c"] :f 1}} :g ["a"]})

(reduce o+ [mapA mapB mapC]) ;; this vector could contain much more maps!
;; => {:a {:b 6, :c {:d 8, :e ["a" "b" "e" "c"], :f 9}}, :g ["b" "c" "a"]}

;; or we could define in addition:
(defmethod o+ :default [& args] (reduce o+ args))
;; which makes `o+` to a variadic function (function which can be
;; called with as many arguments you want)

;; then, whenever we add more than two arguments, it will be activated:
(o+ mapA mapB mapC)
;; => {:a {:b 6, :c {:d 8, :e ["a" "b" "e" "c"], :f 9}}, :g ["b" "c" "a"]}

;; and this also works:
(o+ 1 2 3 4 5 6)
;; => 21
(o+ ["a"] ["b" "c"] ["d"])
;; => ["a" "b" "c" "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [merge-with](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge-with) with a custom function to resolve conflicts when merging maps.

```clj
(defn my-merge [a b]
  (merge-with (fn [a b]
                (if (map? a)
                  (merge-with + a b)
                  (into a b)))
              a b))
```

Or defined recursively:

```clj
(defn my-merge [a b]
  (cond (vector? a) (into a b)
        (number? a) (+ a b)
        (map? a)    (merge-with my-merge a b)
        :else       (throw (ex-info "Unsupported values" {:values [a b]}))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea.  I didn't test this, and I'm quite sure a more clever solution will come... especially now that I said that this is an answer (the someone-said-something-wrong-on-the-internet effect) :)

```
(reduce
  (fn [accum item]
    (let [b-accum (get-in accum [:a :b])
          b-item (get-in item [:a :b])
          new-b (+ b-accum b-item)
          new-c (vec (concat (:c accum) (:c item))]
      {:a {:b new-b} :c new-c}))
 [map1 map2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[net.cgrand.xforms :as x])

(let [map1 {:a {:b 1} :c ["dog"]}
      map2 {:a {:b 2} :c ["cat"]}]
        (->> [map1 map2]
            (into {}
                (x/multiplex
                    {:a (comp (map :a) (map :b) (x/reduce +) (x/into [:b]) (x/into {}))
                     :c (comp (mapcat :c) (x/reduce conj))}))))
```